# ViewChildren-QueryList changes subscription is called for any unrelated DOM changes

Tags: angular, dom, view, subscription, children

In my project, I am having an issue where the view children subscription gets called for any changes in the view. My view children is querying a list of item ElementRefs, however, even if there is no change in the number of items, the change subscription is called when something else changes in the view.How can I stop that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuigne

```js
StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuigne

import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @ViewChildren('itemRef')
  itemRefs = new QueryList<ElementRef>();
  toggle = true;
  items = [ 'Superman', 'Batman', 'Ironman', 'Spiderman', 'Hulk'];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.itemRefs.changes.subscribe(o => {
      this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#output').innerText += 'Changes'; 
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="toggle = !toggle">Toggle: triggers changes in ViewChildren</button>
<h2 *ngIf="toggle">Toggled ON</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="!toggle">Toggled OFF</h2>
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of items" #itemRef>{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Enter superhero">
  <button (click)="name && name.length > 2 ? items.push(name) : return">Add</button>
</div>
<div id="output" style="color: red;margin-top:10px;"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with angular https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30088

Comment: The forum and question seems to be closed.

Comment: yes, the angular team is not going to fix this yet. Maybe in angular 9 it will be fixed.